# Javascript function undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This works in Chrome and FF but not IE:
I call my JS in the middle of the body:

```
 <li><a href="#" onclick="destroy(80)" >Delete</a></li>
```

I load my JS file like this (**just before closing body tag**):

```
<script src="https://thing.test/js/things-common.js"></script>
```

It has a function in like this:

```
function destroy(id)
 swal({

    text: "Do you really want to delete this thing?",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
})
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            //AJAX the delete
            AxiosDestroyThing(id);
        }

    });
}
```

IE (11) gives: `'destroy' is undefined`

I have been developing in Chrome and this is the first time I have had to support IE.

Am I doing something silly?

**Update**

I have added the full code for the function. Is this because the sweet alert (swal) is using ES6?

More details added after comments added.

Comment: pretty hard to help debug this.... Either you call it before the file is loaded, there is some error that is preventing it to load, or 100s of other things.

Comment: Yes, that is why I have asked for help. What should I do next?

Comment: Are there any other errors in the console?

Comment: please provide your html completely and where and when do you call this method ?

Comment: @Mick show some more of your code, what is the order in which this script tag and the function call are in the html and what is in the js file?

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported in IE11. The console is almost definitely giving you a syntax error about that and there's at least one of your problems.

Comment: @JLRishe yes I think you are right, so what can I do about it?

Comment: Well if you have to support IE8, you need to transpiler to convert ES6 to something that IE11 can understand.

Comment: How could I just rewrite the function without the arrow function?

Comment: By using this magic : https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: No magic is needed, just put the word `function` before `(willDelete)` and remove the `=>`.

Answer (score 2):

This was because I was using the arrow function which are ES6.

I changed the function to be:

```
function destroy(id) {
    swal({

        text: "Do you really want to delete this thing?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true
    }).then(function (willDelete) {
        if (willDelete) {
            //AJAX the delete
            AxiosDestroyThing(id);
        }
    });
}
```